# Retrieve the id from a input, no hard coding

Tags: jquery, html

Today I have the id `#klm` as a click event (https://jsfiddle.net/nnvduvm0/2/) in jQuery to display an alert message.

I would like to replace the value `#klm` in click event with `$("input").first().val()` in the click event but it doesn't work (https://jsfiddle.net/zebn6yr7/1/)

I would like to achieve the same result but you retrieve the value of the id from a input that should be used for click event of the button.

```js
$('#klm').click(function() {
    alert($("input").first().val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="klm" id="candy">   
<button id="klm" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: You need to append a `#` to the start of the `#klm` fields' value: https://jsfiddle.net/zebn6yr7/2/. I don't see the point of this code though, as it will only work on the element specified in the `input` on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right answer but when you click the button, the id of button is the value of textbox. Hope this helps

```js
$(".this-button").click(function() 
{
 alert(     $("input").first().val()      );
    $(this).attr("id",  $("input").first().val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="klm" id="candy">
    
<button id="klm" type="button" class="this-button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to say thats an id. So put a hash in front like this:

```
$('#' + $("input").first().val()).click(function() {
    alert($("input").first().val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Code it's working fine

```
$( "#"+$("input").eq(0).val()).click(function() 
  {
    alert(     $("input").eq(0).val()      );
  });

});
```